# How to solve Firbase Crashlytics missing UUID?

Tags: swift, firebase, uuid, crashlytics

Firebase crash reports says missing UUID. Is it related with dysm? How to solve this?

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x105184 (Missing UUID 994db90811a13e43b7df25c09d51368a)
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18e04 (Missing UUID 6ffccf845e0f34b2bcbbbcf98407ea05)
2  Foundation                     0x17fe90 (Missing UUID a2e534d9cdf0397fa41e147559c83893)
3  AppKit                         0x957ac (Missing UUID a773dd23b1c83c9b91759a71d210ace0)
4  AppKit                         0x9506c (Missing UUID a773dd23b1c83c9b91759a71d210ace0)
5  AppKit                         0x94050 (Missing UUID a773dd23b1c83c9b91759a71d210ace0)
6  SafariPlatformSupport          0x3f08 (Missing UUID 7587af6dc4f83a3d87ed982ba65121bf)
7  SafariPlatformSupport          0x3d68 (Missing UUID 7587af6dc4f83a3d87ed982ba65121bf)
8  UIKitCore                      0xb302b8 (Missing UUID d9410dddc83c314496892f65b936a9ce)
9  UIKitCore                      0xb3a4c8 (Missing UUID d9410dddc83c314496892f65b936a9ce)
10 UIKitCore                      0x81a94c (Missing UUID d9410dddc83c314496892f65b936a9ce)
11 UIKitCore                      0x81a138 (Missing UUID d9410dddc83c314496892f65b936a9ce)
12 UIKitCore                      0x18a504 (Missing UUID d9410dddc83c314496892f65b936a9ce)
13 WebKit                         0x7e1098 (Missing UUID aa13ddaad5bc30a5bfc154f853570c6e)
14 WebKit                         0x3fb8f4 (Missing UUID aa13ddaad5bc30a5bfc154f853570c6e)
15 WebKit                         0x74b40c (Missing UUID aa13ddaad5bc30a5bfc154f853570c6e)
16 WebKit                         0x31b900 (Missing UUID aa13ddaad5bc30a5bfc154f853570c6e)
17 WebKit                         0x4e47d4 (Missing UUID aa13ddaad5bc30a5bfc154f853570c6e)
18 WebKit                         0x316024 (Missing UUID aa13ddaad5bc30a5bfc154f853570c6e)
19 WebKit                         0x3156d8 (Missing UUID aa13ddaad5bc30a5bfc154f853570c6e)
20 JavaScriptCore                 0x1a6014 (Missing UUID 3304ba288b4734048dec3b99449f520f)
21 JavaScriptCore                 0x1a6db0 (Missing UUID 3304ba288b4734048dec3b99449f520f)
22 CoreFoundation                 0x85034 (Missing UUID 994db90811a13e43b7df25c09d51368a)
23 CoreFoundation                 0x84f80 (Missing UUID 994db90811a13e43b7df25c09d51368a)
24 CoreFoundation                 0x84c80 (Missing UUID 994db90811a13e43b7df25c09d51368a)
25 CoreFoundation                 0x83600 (Missing UUID 994db90811a13e43b7df25c09d51368a)
26 CoreFoundation                 0x82b24 (Missing UUID 994db90811a13e43b7df25c09d51368a)
27 HIToolbox                      0x32338 (Missing UUID f842b96a54f336f39b94b258fae1b7eb)
28 HIToolbox                      0x320b4 (Missing UUID f842b96a54f336f39b94b258fae1b7eb)
29 HIToolbox                      0x31e68 (Missing UUID f842b96a54f336f39b94b258fae1b7eb)
30 AppKit                         0x4178c (Missing UUID a773dd23b1c83c9b91759a71d210ace0)
31 AppKit                         0x40084 (Missing UUID a773dd23b1c83c9b91759a71d210ace0)
32 AppKit                         0x32250 (Missing UUID a773dd23b1c83c9b91759a71d210ace0)
33 AppKit                         0x396c (Missing UUID a773dd23b1c83c9b91759a71d210ace0)
34 AppKit                         0x2d9a80 (Missing UUID a773dd23b1c83c9b91759a71d210ace0)
35 UIKitMacHelper                 0x53b0 (Missing UUID 116be57b2d4436298891b807ebb81cdd)
36 UIKitCore                      0x3b60 (Missing UUID d9410dddc83c314496892f65b936a9ce)
37 ZoodMall                       0x6ce0 main + 13 (AppDelegate.swift:13)
38 ???                            0x1083b108c (Missing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is related to dSYMs. One option would be trying to find those missing dSYMs locally. For this:

1. Run this command to list all the available dSYMs in your machine: `mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done`
2. If you can find the same UUIDs, then you can upload those dSYMs to Crashlytics. The easiest way would be using the Crashlytics dashboard where you can drag and drop them.

However, if you cannot find them, the suggestion would be:

1. Make sure Xcode is [generating dSYMs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#check-xcode).
2. Configure Xcode for [uploading dSYMs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#set-up-dsym-uploading) automatically.
3. I crease the version/build number (just to help you differentiate this version)
4. Make a small code change so Xcode generates a new UUID and dSYMs.
5. Then build and run the app and then cause a new [test crash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#force-test-crash).

If everything went well, the new crash should have symbolicated frames. Note that this fixes this issue for new crashes, older crashes won't be symbolicated.